# Converting mysql to mysqli functions and getting parameter error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to mysqli and am upgrading all my code to use it.

I understand functions now need to have the `$conn` variable included with them.

Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM...";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result)) {
}
```

I'm getting the error:

`PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`

and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: A suggestion would be to [check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) if you're wondering how to use a function. The manual is pretty extensive and usually have really good examples (and comments).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a typo, since the OP simply passed the wrong arguments to the function.

Comment: This could be helpful for people in future who make the same mistake.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I wouldn't call it a typo, but a fundamental misunderstanding of API: "I understand functions now need to have the `$conn` variable included with them." A typo is `loc` for `Ioc`, followed by a slap on forehead; this was not it.

Comment: @Amadan - If you read the documentation about the functions in this question, the usage is pretty clear. In my opinion, SO shouldn't be a secondary documentation. Some functions/features can be murky where it's good that there's a SO post about it, but I don't think this really fits that description. (Again, this is just my opinion). Sure, "typo" might be a bit strange for this, but can't find a better match =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Missing? Nothing. Extra? :)

`mysqli_fetch_array` will take `$result`, which already knows about `$conn`; so `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` is correct, and adding `$conn` confuses it.

Comment: Then you've likely taken it out of the different place in code.

Comment: Changed to 
`$query = "SELECT * FROM...";`
`$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);`
`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`
`}`

Comment: That should be correct. Please recheck that the message text isn't changed, and doesn't point to some other line in code.

Comment: @DanielWilliams - Do a `var_dump($result)` and check what it contains. If it's "false", then your query failed. You can use [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out why.

Comment: Previously the error reported `object given`. Now it's `boolean given`.

Comment: @DanielWilliams - That's because you're query failed. See my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, I should have checked the query. Slap on wrist. That was the problem.

Comment: And the error message! :) Fixing one error can cause another to show its face... you shouldn't just assume the error was not fixed. Anyway, good guidance is at `mysqli_query`: "Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`."